# Toggle a volatile boolean in Java

Tags: java

I notice that the following code doesn't toggle the flag as it is intended to be (the flag value remains the same after toggleFlag is called). Why is this the case?

```
private static volatile boolean flag;

static synchronized void toggleFlag() {
   flag = !flag;
}
```

Comment: Your code compiles? It's weird because you can't access instance properties inside a static context

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible for the code you put to compile, leave running.

Your code has multiple errors, for example,

1. You can't access a `non-static` variable(`flag` in this case) from a `static` method(`toggle()` in this case).
2. Proper declaration of `toggle()` method is, `static synchronized void toggle()`

Correct code:

```
private static volatile boolean flag;

static synchronized void toggle()
{
 flag = !flag;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I am not asking him to accept this as an answer. I wanted to explain the mistakes in comments but it was getting lengthy and congested.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `this` with static variable.

In static block or a static method, there is no instance to refer to, and therefore the `this` keyword is not permitted.

Check this out:

```
private static volatile boolean flag;

    static synchronized void toggleFlag() {
        flag = !flag;
    }
```

From docs.oracle.com:

> Not all combinations of instance and class variables and methods are allowed:
>
> - Instance methods can access instance variables and instance methods
>   directly.
> - Instance methods can access class variables and class methods
>   directly.
> - Class methods can access class variables and class methods directly.
> - Class methods cannot access instance variables or instance methods directly—they must use an object reference. Also, class methods cannot
>   use the this keyword as there is no instance for this to refer to.

Link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

UPD. When you create `boolean` variable such as `private static volatile boolean flag;` it becomes `false` by default. So using this code `toggleFlag();` means `!false`.

You can check the Default Values section in Primitive Data Types for more information about the class members default values.

Link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html